# Error while using CronR

Tags: r

I am trying to run a script every hour using cronR but getting error

```
library(cronR)

f <- system.file(package = "cronR", "extdata","/Users/abhishekgupta/Documents/Personal/hackathons/mckinsey/hackathon.R")
cmd <- cron_rscript(f)
cmd
```

> Error in cron_rscript(f) : file.exists(rscript) is not TRUE

Comment: looks like your script file either does not exist or is at another location

Comment: I have tried different files it is giving error for all.

Comment: what does `file.exists("/Users/abhishekgupta/Documents/Personal/hackathons/mckinsey/hackathon.R")` return? `file.choose()` can help get the correct path

Comment: file.exists("/Users/abhishekgupta/Documents/Personal/hackathons/mckinsey/hackathon.R") returns TRUE

Comment: I think you might want `cron_rscript("/Users/abhishekgupta/Documents/Personal/hackathons/mckinsey/hackathon.R")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
but as per Richard's suggestion,

```
cmd <- cron_rscript("/Users/abhishekgupta/Documents/Personal/hackathons/mckinsey/hackathon.R")
cron_add(cmd, frequency = 'minutely', id = 'job1', description = 'some crawler')
```

indeed works!
Thank you for the hint Richard!